# Hotkey in vs code to switch between python interactive window and active editor?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a hotkey ( or a command you can assign one to ) in vs code to switch the cursor between a python interactive window and an active editor widnow?

Comment: have you tried `Ctrl+backtick` (key next to 1)

Comment: @rioV8 that goes to terminal, not the python interactive window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CTRL+1 and CTRL+2 will switch between groups. So if you have the interactive window in one group and your code in another, you can uses these shortcuts to switch between them.

Comment: Thanks, that's the ticket!  If there were something like "alt tab" that just goes back and forth, that's the only thing better, but this is so close, AND, the cursor doesn't disappear ( I was trying something else and the cursor moved off of the input of the interactive window )

Comment: My cursor does disappear from interactive window with CTRL+1, and, upon returning to the interactive window with CTRL+2, my keyboard just controls the scrollbar... :_(

Comment: My cursor does not remain active when switching to the interactive pane (using command-2 on a Mac). Does anyone have a working solution to easily jump between the editor and interactive panes that keeps the cursors active? Tx

Comment: @footfalcon Not ideal but I've been pressing CTRL+2, then SHIFT+hold tab, which cycles through a few windows and eventually resets on the interactive input.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to switch between those without issues as of now, check these issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/97992
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/12066

Answer (score 0):

The way the run code to interactive was somehow not specified correctly in
jupyter v.2021.10.11....

I added the following to the user defined keyboard shortcuts

```
[{
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
  }]
```

so now "control" + ";"
runs it in interactive without changing other short cuts.